# nodemailer gmail working on localhost (windows) but not on google vm instance debian

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, nodemailer

Maybe someone here can help.
I have simple page running on node server. everything running good on windows while developing in VScode and on google compute engine instance apart from send email using gmail smtp.
I'm using App password generate by google on my account. this password working while i start my app on localhost on windows. But when i upload my app to debian VM instance i get error from google bad credentials. this is the code.

```
const nodeMailer = require('nodemailer');

class Mail {
  constructor(server) {
    this.server = server;
    this.#init();
  }
  #init() {
    this.#setTransporter();
    this.server.post("/", (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.body);
      this.transporter.sendMail(this.#getMailOptions(req), (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
          res.send(error.toString());
        } else {
          res.send('success');
        }
      });
    });
  }
  #getMailOptions(req) {
    return {
      from: req.body.email,
      to: process.env.EMAIL,
      subject: `Mail from adam-hajduk.com ${req.body.subject}`,
      text: `Message from ${req.body.email} ${req.body.firstname + ' ' + req.body.lastname}: \n\n ${req.body.message}`,
    }
  }
  #setTransporter() {
    this.transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.USER,
        pass: process.env.PASS,
      },
    });
  }
}

module.exports = Mail;
```

If try to replace already ports, host "smtp.gmail.com" to different option on internet without secure etc. Can.t understand why this code working on Windows local machine and not on google vm instnce linux machine.

```
this.transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      port: 587,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.USER,
        pass: process.env.PASS,
      },
    });
```

also tried this. All of the sollutios work on windows in VC Code local machine but not on cloud.
always same error Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials f14-20020a92cb4e000000b003295ff72e80sm554939ilq.84 - gsmtp